# Is This a Bug? Can't Specify form id using form_for in Padrino

Tags: ruby, haml, padrino

I have this form_for tag:

```
= form_for @food, :autocomplete => "off", :id => "food" do |f|
```

This is the tag it generates:

```
<form action-autocomplete="off" action-id="food" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

How can I specify the html form id attribute from the form_for tag?  Note that padrino has added an "action" before the autocomplete attribute as well.

This looks like a bug to me.  I'm using version 0.12.2 of Padrino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the URL as the second parameter in case you want to use a custom id. The code should be:

```
= form_for @food, '/path/to/create/', id: 'food' do |f|
```

[`code for form_for`](https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/blob/master/padrino-helpers/lib/padrino-helpers/form_helpers.rb#L44)

This is a similar pattern adopted from Rails. [In Rails, however](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for), you don't have to specify the URL as the second argument and the HTML-based settings go in to the `html` option key. Worth opening an issue for this.

Comment: Apparently using the empty string for the url parameter will suffice for posting back to the same url.